# firefox preloads all html5 media data inspite of preload=metadata

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, html5-audio

First, I'm very new here, so please forgive my ignorance and possible errors.

I've encountered a strange problem with firefox, which I don't seem to be able to remidy.

I've built a html5 media player for my website(s) using php, html5 and JavaScript. The strange thing is, that Firefox (41) shows some very inconsistent behaviour with buffering and preloading media data. Chromium, IE and Opera do this very nice, and load, as requested, only all metadata and the media-data needed to play the current file, and also in a very bandwidth-saving manner. Only Firefox shows some strange behaviour. Metadata gets loaded nicely, but once play() is called it loads all data at once at full speed, which results in very heavy traffic and the inability to fetch the needed data in time.

You can check it here: https://musicchris.de/index.php?page=media

Example:
I load the page, and click on some playlist item, which is very far down the list. Now FF starts to load all data, and of course it starts at the first items, and the data for the lower items arrives very late. This is very annoying and makes the player unusable on slower connections.

Now I'm not very sure on this, but I guess html5 leaves the buffering and caching up to the browser - at least I haven't found any useful docs, how I could manipulate that behaviour.

So the question is:
What could I do, to prevent FF from loading all media-data, when only a specific media file is needed? And how could I slow down the traffic? No need to load a mp3 with full bandwidth.

And I guess, why this player doesn't work at all on all Safari-browsers is another question/thread...

Thanks for any ideas!

chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily, [my first attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378148/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-select-audio-file-from-button-value) to contribute to stackoverflow, gave me one possible answer! :D

If I use a different approach, namely dynamically create an <audio> or <video> element with JS, instead of pulling all of them into the HTML at once, solves this problem. The trick is to start with an empty media-list, then remove all media-tags everytime the current media changes, and then create a new one, only for the next desired media element. Always replace the old media element with the new one!

And it was one more learning experience, to find out that removing/empty the src-attribute cancels the loading-process altogether.

Still, I'd love to hear more interesting ideas on this! For example, if you know, how to manipulate buffering behaviour of a browser, I'd like to hear...